# Check file's content for even, odd or non-number characters and manage them appropriately

Tags: bash

The program takes 3 arguments: input file, output file for even numbers and output file for odd numbers.

The task is to check the input and to put numbers into the proper files. 
There can be other non-numeric characters in the input.

In the end we need to provide user with the information how many odd, even and other characters were found.

Here's a sample input file:

```
1 2 3 4 52
9 2 32
1 2 a
9 2
```

sample output file for even:

```
2 4 52
2 32
2
2
```

and sample output file for odd:

```
1 3
9
1
9
```

And here's my current solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
in=$1
even=$2
odd=$3

regex='^[0-9]+$'

num_even=0
num_odd=0
non_num=0

while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    for number in $line; do
        number=`echo "$number" | xargs`
        if [[ $number =~ $regex ]]; then
            if [[ $(( $number % 2 )) == 0 ]]; then
                printf "$number " >> $even
                num_even=$(($num_even+1))
            else
                printf " $number" >> $odd
                num_odd=$(($num_odd+1))
            fi
        else
            non_num=$(($non_num+1))
        fi
    done
    printf "\n" >> $even
    printf "\n" >> $odd
done <$in

echo "Even numbers: " $num_even
echo "Odd numbers: " $num_odd
echo "Non num characters: " $non_num
```

It is working fine, however I'm very new to Bash and I wonder what could I've done better. Thank you! :)

Comment: This type of question is more appropriate for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @chepner, thanks, I didn't know that page.

Comment: It looks OK to me, especially if you're starting out.

Comment: Why `number=\`echo "$number" | xargs\``?

Comment: @123 That's a good question. When I wanted to perform modulo on e.g. "1 " an error occured, therefore I needed to get rid of white characters. Do you have better solution?

Answer (score 1):

try: one more approach also here with awk.

**EDIT:**

```
awk '{
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)              {           ###Starting a for loop here starting from i variable value from 1 to till NF value.
        if($i%2==0 && $i ~ /[0-9]/)     {           ###Checking condition here if value of a field if it is completly dived by 0 and having digits in it.
        count_even++;                               ###Counting even numbers here and incrementing it by 1 each time.
        printf("%s%s",$i,i==NF?"":" ") > "even_file";### printing the value of that field and printing either space, #if it is not the last field and print NULL if last field of the line.
                                        }
        else if($i%2!=0 && $i ~ /[0-9]/){           ###Checking condition if value of any field is null completly divided by 2 and it is having digits too in it.
        count_odd++;                                ###Counting odd numbers here and incrementing it by 1 each time.
        printf("%s%s",$i,i==NF?"":" ") > "odd_file";###printing field value with space or null depending on its field number for last field it will be null.
                                        }
        else if($i !~ /[0-9]/)          {
        count_non_digit++;                          ###Counting non-digit values and incrementing them each time by 1.
                                        }
                                        };
        print "" > "even_file";                     ###Printing a new line into file named even_file.
        print "" > "odd_file";                      ###Printing a new line into file named odd_file.
    }
        END                             {
        print "Even numbers: ",count_even;         ###Printing the even count here.
        print "Odd numbers: ",count_odd;           ###Printing the odd count here.
        print "Non numeric characters: ",count_non_digit; ###Printing the non-digit count here.
                                        }
   '  Input_file                                   ###Mentioning Input_file here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Complex ***awk*** solution:

```
awk '{ even=odd=""; 
       for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {    # iterating though the fields of the line
           if ($i!~/^[0-9]+$/) { a["other"]++; continue }   # processing non-digit value
           if ($i%2) { odd=(odd=="")? $i:odd FS $i; a["odd"]++; } 
           else { even=(even=="")? $i:even FS $i; a["even"]++; } 
       } 
       if (even!="") print even >> "even.txt";   # redirecting resulting `even` values into respective file
       if (odd!="") print odd >> "odd.txt" 
     }
     END{ 
        print "Even numbers: "a["even"]; 
        print "Odd numbers: "a["odd"]; 
        print "Non numeric characters: "a["other"] 
     }' input
```

The output:

```
Even numbers: 7
Odd numbers: 5
Non numeric characters: 1
```

---

*even.txt* contents:

```
2 4 52
2 32
2
2
```

*odd.txt* contents:

```
1 3
9
1
9
```